# Sharepoint 2013: Rest API - does header need to include X-RequestDigest?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, request-digest

I'm making progress in learning to use the rest API (HTTP web service) in SPD.

WF1: Acivates to a change to a list. WF1 is suppose to launch WF2 using the Rest API. Within WF1 I have the WF2 GUID and the list ID where the change occured.

WF2: At the moment, just logs to workflow history.

```
[web site]_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/StartWorkflowOnListItemBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId=’[WF2_GUID]’,itemId=’[ItemID]’)
```

The request header:

```
Accept : application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type : application/json;odata=verbose
```

The response code = OK, but the WF is not launching. Does the X-RequestDigest need to be populated for the POST to work?

Note - I'm not doing any coding. Trying to keep this OOTB.

Kind regards,

Comment: Thanks for the help people. At least now I get HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden rather than HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request. Moving on.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of the RequestDigest as a key that opens the cabinet.

- You can GET information without opening it.
- There is information you cannot GET without opening it.
- You **need** the key to PUT (POST) information in

Comment: Danny I'm already passing in an Oauth token as an `Authorization` header, yet I still need `RequestDigest`? (testing using Postman). What value then should `RequestDigest` be? The same as `Authorization` token? I tried that and still get `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException — The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

Comment: [I have left the SP world, yeah!] You need to call the contextinfo endpoint and get the value: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=requestdigest+contextinfo

Comment: @Growler I agree .Since you're already using OAuth this shouldn't be necessary. [MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints?redirectedfrom=MSDN#writing-data-by-using-the-rest-interface) say this: "If you're using the authentication and authorization flow described in [Authorization and authentication of SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/authorization-and-authentication-of-sharepoint-add-in), you don't need to include the request digest in your requests."

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You do need it for anything other than "GET". And it doesn't hurt with that, so I recommend using it for all requests.

See [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx) about halfway down the page...

> The way you get and send the form digest value depends on the add-in
>   When you send a POST request, the request must include the form digest
>   value in the X-RequestDigest header. However, the way you get and send
>   the value differs by add-in:

It then goes on to say how you do that with different environments.

Comment: Just to be precise: it **does** hurt with certain GET requests. Using it on a GET with `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl` will return a 400 (spent 4 hours debugging this).

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is required for POST, below are snapshot from MSDN.

Another important consideration when creating, updating, and deleting SharePoint entities is that if you aren’t using OAuth to authorize your requests, these operations require the server’s request form digest value as the value of the X-RequestDigest header. You can retrieve this value by making a POST request with an empty body to http:///_api/contextinfo and extracting the value of the d:FormDigestValue node in the XML that the contextinfo endpoint returns. The following example shows an HTTP request to the contextinfo endpoint in C#.

[Reference link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Since OP has mentioned in responses that they are using an OAuth token, then the answer is **no**, you don't need to use `X-RequestDigest`.

[The documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints?redirectedfrom=MSDN#writing-data-by-using-the-rest-interface) on this is explicit:

> Another important consideration when creating, updating, and deleting
> SharePoint entities is that *if you aren't using OAuth to authorize
> your requests*, these operations require the server's request form
> digest value as the value of the X-RequestDigest header.

followed by

> If you're using the authentication and authorization flow described in
> [Authorization and authentication of SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/authorization-and-authentication-of-sharepoint-add-ins), *you don't need
> to include the request digest in your requests*.

I successfully use OAuth for my requests and do not need to specify it.

Comment: I verified that this is correct for Sharepoint Online.  I can't speak for SP2013.  Using OAuth with a Sharepoint App Identity and passing an Bearer access token with requests (GET or POST), I am able to read and write content to lists/document libraries without the X-RequestDigest header.