# Get sharepoint REST api digest header

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, item-attachment

I am trying to build an angular 4 app to talk to sharepoint sub site(not root site) level lists for attachments.

The very first challenge I am facing is to be able to call the APIs which fails with authroization error. Some research indicated that I need to pass digest token by getting from `<host>/_api_contextinfo` call.

However, I am not able find an example to do that either.

please advise.

Comment: Hello, have you checked this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199187/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-does-header-need-to-include-x-requestdigest and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159609/how-to-get-request-digest-value-from-provider-hosted-app

Comment: yep and this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244402/sharepoint-2013-remote-authentication-in-rest-api . i am having hard time in get digest info by making call as it thorws me access denied. not sure what is missing